# How to pass attrs to forms.DateField?

Tags: django, django-forms

In forms.py I have this:

```
date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(
years=range(datetime.date.today().year - 15, 1920, -1)))
```

to create a select. I want to pass to it, `attrs={'class': 'form-control'}` I tried in different ways but with no results.

Comment: `attrs` is an argument to the widget, not the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That kind of information gets passed to widgets:

```
date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
    widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(
        years=range(datetime.date.today().year - 15, 1920, -1),
        attrs={'class': 'form-control',}
    )
)
```